# How to achieve better performance on scroll event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add a color background to navbar if the user scrolls down. When the value of the scrollY equals 0, the background of nav becomes transparent.

I added a scroll event in the **componentDidMount** life cycle method. Inside this I put a function that changes state. It works, but when I scroll the performance drops dramatically, I have no idea how to make it more smoothly.

While state.open equals true the nav element receive class.

```
componentDidMount() {

window.addEventListener("scroll", this.activeNavTab, {
  passive: true,
  });
 }

activeNavTab() {
 if (window.scrollY > 0) {
   this.setState(() => ({ navTab: true }));
 } else {
  this.setState(() => ({ navTab: false }));
 }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.activeNavTab);
}
```

**Question 2**

Manipulating DOM elements in own custom method is a good practice? For example:

```
toggleMenu() {
 document.body.classList.toggle("disablescroll");
 this.setState((prevState) => ({ open: !prevState.open }));
}
```

Comment: Answering question 2. It is not good practice because it is not the *react* way to do it. I personally do not really mind, because sometimes there is no way around it, but most of the time you should stick to the practices of the framework you use. Your main problem seems to be that the `setState` fires on every scroll several times. Maybe add a console log there to see how often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't call `this.activeNavTab` each time when scroll method works... Call it with delay...The easiest way to do it is to wrap your function with `lodash` function `debounce`. It should improve perfomance

```
const delay = 500
const activeNavTabDebounced = _.debounce(this.activeNavTab, delay)
window.addEventListener("scroll", activeNavTabDebounced, {
  passive: true,
});
```

and then kill it with

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener("scroll", activeNavTabDebounced);
}
```

Comment: I like your answer, but directly calling _.debounce this way make not easy to removeEventListener later